# Xmonad showing only 1 window on screen

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I decided to try Xmonad today and installed it on VM with Arch linux. Without spacing it works perfectly, but when I am adding it, Xmonad only show one newest window on screen (if I open new window, old one just disappear).
There is my simple configuration I made using information from [there](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.17.0/docs/XMonad-Layout-Spacing.html):

```
import XMonad
import Xmonad.Layout.Spacing

main :: IO ()
main = xmonad $ def
    { layoutHook = spacingWithEdge 10 $ Full
    }
```

Sorry if I am being dumb. This is my first time using Xmonad and Haskell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration replaces the default `layoutHook` with one that only makes the `Full` layout available. Changing the relevant line to...

```
    { layoutHook = spacingWithEdge 10 $ layoutHook def
```

... should add the spacing while keeping all the default layouts available. Note that:

- You can switch between the available layouts, with the default key binding being Alt + Space; and
- You can switch the focused window, even while using the `Full` layout, with the default key binding being Alt + Tab.